# do I use MsmqIntegrationBinding or netMsmqBinding?

Tags: wcf, msmq, wcf-binding, netmsmqbinding, msmqintegrationbinding

my company bought a third party application.  There's no documentation, there's no support.  this application is using .net, and it creates a queue.

I need to write an application to pick up the message as soon as it gets to the queue.

which binding I should use?  I read the difference between these two binding. still confused which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This decision must be depend on your third party application. **NetMsmqBinding**  used full only if you have both side WCF application. If your application push message without WCF then you have to go ahead with **MsmqIntegrationBinding**.